# Selecting URL on same table row as text in different <td>

Tags: xml, xpath, xhtml

I have a table that I am trying to scrape, it looks like the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqvVD.jpg

Here is the HTML of one row in the table:

```
<TR >

            <script>
                  if (document.getElementById("Function").value != 'Customer')
                            document.write('<td align="center">CO</td>');</script>
            <td align="left"><a href="OrdDetList.pgm?Order=8M216&Purpose=Customer&ShowPrice=&OpenOnly=Y">8M216 </a></td>
             <script> if (document.getElementById("Function").value != 'Customer')
                            document.write('<td align="center">R</td> <td align="center">O</td>');</script>
                            <td align="center">Backordered</td>
            <td align="left"><a href="OrdersList.pgm?Customer=33333&CompDiv=all&Function=Customer&OpenOnly=Y&ShowPrice= &YearsBack=      ">70036</a>
                    <a class=info href="#"><img src="../images/help.gif" border=none>
                        <span>
                        <div id="SoldToNameAddress">
                    123 our address<br>
                        </div>
                        </span>
                            </a>
                    </td>
            <td align="left">our company</td>
            <td align="left"><a href="OrdersList.pgm?Customer=33333&CompDiv=all&Function=Customer&OpenOnly=Y&ShowPrice= &YearsBack=      ">70037</a>
                    <a class=info href="#"><img src="../images/help.gif" border=none>
                        <span>
                        <div id="ShipToNameAddress">
                    our address
                        </div>
                        </span>
                            </a>
                    </td>
            <td align="left">our company name</td>
            <td align="left">70037</td>
            <td align="left">052317</td>
        <script>
                  if (document.getElementById("Function").value != 'Customer')
                            document.write('<td align="center">3</td>');</script>
            <td align="left"><a class=info href="#">17/05/23<span>May 23, 2017        </span></a></td>
            <td align="left"><a class=info href="#">17/05/23<span>May 23, 2017        </span></a></td>
            <td align="center"></td>

        </TR>
```

My goal is to select the URL:

```
<a href="OrdDetList.pgm?Order=8M216&Purpose=Customer&ShowPrice=&OpenOnly=Y">8M216 </a>
```

When our PO is searched `<td align="left">052317</td>`

I am very new to using Xpath so the furthest I am able to get so far is being able to directly get the URL by search for 8M216. But I am not sure how I can use XPATH to give me the other URL based on the PO 052317 in the other table cell.

Here is my code so far but its kind of useless because of what I said above:

```
<?php

$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

$html = file_get_contents('https://thewebsiteiamscraping', false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)); //get the html returned from the following url

$order_doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors

if(!empty($html)){ //if any html is actually returned

    $order_doc->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_clear_errors(); //remove errors for yucky html

    $order_xpath = new DOMXPath($order_doc);

    //get order URLS based on our PO#
    $order_row = $order_xpath->query('//a[text()="8M216 "]/@href');

    if($order_row->length > 0){
        foreach($order_row as $row){
            echo $row->nodeValue . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but what version of HTML is the code snippet supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Think this XPath instruction will help you to find correct XPath

[image]

You can open a Console in Chrome, and check the XPath by typing `$x("your_xpath_here")`. This will return an array of matched values. If it is empty, you know there is no match on the page.

Comment: That was exactly what I needed to see and its working thanks so much!